# Pass form value to cfc

Tags: coldfusion

I have a cfc where a function returns a query with a list of employees which is displayed in a table. I have a sorting form on the page, where onclick of the column heading the data needs to be sorted based on which column is being clicked. Now, I had this all working as long as all the queries were on the page itself. I am trying to move the queries to a cfc now. I am sure I am missing something basic here. Can anyone please point me to how to get the sorted by results from the cfc onclick of the column header?

```
 <script>
      function submitformnow(x){
      if (document.form.show.value == "DESC")
       {$('input[name=show]').val('ASC');}
          else{ $('input[name=show]').val('DESC');}
           $('input[name=order_by]').val(x);
           document.form.submit();
          }
    </script>

 <cffunction name="getemps" access="public" output="false" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="emp_id" type="numeric" default="#variables.emp_id#" />
    <cfargument name="order_by" default="#variables.order_by#" type="string" required="no">
    <cfargument name="show" default="#variables.show#" type="string" required="no">

    <cfquery name="qemps" datasource="test">
        select * from emps
      <cfif len(trim(arguments.order_by)) and arguments.order_by NEQ '' and len(trim(arguments.show)) and arguments.show NEQ '' >
       ORDER BY #arguments.order_by# #arguments.show#
       </cfif>
    </cfquery>
</cffunction>
<cfset employee= new cfcs.employees() />
<cfset getemps = employee.getemps(emp_id,order_by,show) />//order_by, show are the form field here//
```

Comment: What you're looking for is probably better handled through a front end tool like datatables http://datatables.net/

Comment: What does the `<form>` look like?  Is the employee ID a form field?

Comment: You should validate `arguments.order_by` and `arguments.show` in your query. As is, it would be vulnerable to SQL injection since they're passed in straight from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<cfset getemps = employee.getemps(form.emp_id,form.order_by,form.show)>
```

Also remember to  your form. variables, before referencing them to make sure they exist.

```
<cfparam name="form.emp_id" default=0>
<cfparam name="form.order_by" default="">
<cfparam name="form.show" default="ASC">
<cfset getemps = employee.getemps(form.emp_id,form.order_by,form.show)>
```